Wacom One tablet only works once (-ish)
I have a Wacom One tablet attached to my Fedora 40 system. At one point it worked fine, but at some point -- and I am unsure exactly when -- it developed very weird behavior: I can make one or two pen strokes on it and then it will stop working; it no longer responds to the pen at all. However, if I switch to another application and then switch back, it starts working again. Usually.
And sometimes it just mysteriously works for a longer chunk of time.
I see the same behavior with Krita, Xournal++, and other pen-enabled programs.
I am hoping someone else has seen similar behavior and can provide some pointers on either diagnosing or resolving the problem.
